# Best way to find a range of integers when you don't know if the start or end is greater in Python

Tags: python, range

I'm playing AdventOfCode Day 5 (https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/5) and
one of the things I like about it is that it let's you think about how
to solve problems better.

Today:

I want to get a range between two integer numbers that includes both numbers.
It it not known in advance which number is higher.

This code works, but it's ugly and hard to read.

```
list(range(a, b + (1 if a < b else -1), 1 if a < b else -1))
```

returns for a=4, b=7:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and for a=7, b=4:

```
[7, 6, 5, 4]
```

Is there an **easier**, Pythonic way of getting the range **without using any new (temporary)** variables and writing a lot of code?

Answer (score 1):

This may be easier to understand and read, which is what "Pythonic" means to me:

```
if a <= b:
    r = range(a, b + 1)
else
    r = range(a, b - 1, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot easier to read. It is doing the a > b comparison manually and I'm looking to.avoid having to do that. (Hoping for some hidden standard library range that already does this or something else I missed)

Comment: There is no stdlib range for that. There is probably a clever hack or one-liner but it will almost certainly be less readable, less efficient, or both..

Comment: the same in 2 lines: `direction = -1 if a > b else 1; r = range(a, b+direction, direction)`; but yes, another variable